# Is it possible to extract a method to a base class in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I have a class `B` which extends class `A`. Now I want to refactor class `B` and extract a method to class `A` with the *Extract Method* refactor operation (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>). Is there any possibility to accomplish this in eclipse?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the method and select **Refactor** > **Pull Up...**. There is no keyboard shortcut for that refactoring by default, but you can assign one via the *Preferences* dialog if you want.

The *Extract method* refactoring (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>) does not support creating the new method directly in a super class, so if that's what you're trying to do you'll have to first do the *Extract method* in class `B` and then use *Pull Up...* refactoring to move it to `A`.

Comment: Thank you mate! Exactly what i've searched for :)